# Error using plotly in Rstudio - unused argument plot$data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Even while using the sample code given in `ggplotly` help function... I'm continuously getting the below error

> Error in map_layout(panel, plot$facet, layer_data, plot$data) :
>   unused argument (plot$data)

Comment: My guess is that some package loaded later than `ggplotly` has its own function called `map_layout` with different arguments. Can you give us the `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: If coffeeinjubky is right you could try calling plotly directly using 'plotly::' before your function name.

Comment: @coffeinjunky- I the sessionInfo() output is below.

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.10.0  googleVis_0.5.10 plotly_2.0.16    ggplot2_2.1.0

Comment: I am having the same problem with the `ggtern` package.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and followed the solution suggested by @royr2. Specifically, I installed the development version of plotly using `devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")` and restarted my R session and reloaded the package. After that, `ggplotly` worked again in RStudio.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't an answer per se, but this has been documented as known issue with ggplot 2.1.0 - see link:

https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/481